# State in BPMN diagram

Tags: bpmn

How to represent *state* in BPMN diagrams?

I have a BPMN diagram describing behavior of an entity. There are some actions and arrows between the actions. I would like to express that between two given actions the entity is in a particular state.

Is is possible in BPMN?

Answer (score 6):

In BPMN *Data Modeling* is used for such aim. In process modelling it is essential to model the items (objects) which are manipulated and used during the execution of the process. The most common element for doing this in BPMN is **Data Object**, which is typically pictured like this

[image]

According BPMN 2.0 specification:

> The primary construct for modeling data within the Process flow is the DataObject element. A DataObject has a well-defined lifecycle, with resulting access constraints.
>   The Data Object class is an item-aware element. Data Object elements MUST be contained within Process or Sub-
>   Process elements.

Moreover, if we stick to your question, there is special attribute of Data Object which is called **DataState**. According the specification:

> Data Object elements can optionally reference a DataState element, which is the state of the data contained in the
>   Data Object. The definition of these states, e.g.,
>   possible values and any specific semantic are out of scope of this International Standard.

As you can see, these states are not well-documented and implemented not by all vendors. For example, [Camunda](https://docs.camunda.org/javadoc/camunda-bpm-platform/7.3/org/camunda/bpm/model/bpmn/instance/DataState.html) supports it.

Answer (score -1):

Another approach that often works is to name the activities using verb-noun combinations that describe the state change. If "Ship order" has been completed (and there is no gateway with loopback) the state of the order can be inferred to be "shipped".

I see BPMN processes as primarily activity-oriented. Activities are expressed directly, whereas object state is often expressed indirectly. A BPMN process diagram is not a state diagram. (The difference has been the topic of several discussions between me and business analysts etc used to modelling state for classic data-centric applications.)

Comment: Well, it is intuitive for humans to infer "Shipped" from "Ship order" activity, but it is completely impossible to do programatically. The thing is, I need to connect parts of a BPMN process with a state in the implementation (with invariants valid for given stage of the process).

Comment: So, you don't execute the BPMN diagram in a process engine (BPMS)? If you do, I definitely prefer giving the BPMS sole responsibility of keeping process state (to me, this means: which particular tasks/activities - one or many - are open?), even if there is an external system of record (SoR).

I wonder if you could use a signal intermediate send event with the state as label, following the relevant task/s/. Either the signal is received by SoR, which will then set the state there or the implementation of the preceding task will update the state at the end of its implementation.

Comment: I'm researching possibilities of automated software synthesis to implement non-human participants in a BPMN process. I use the events to model interactions between them, but I need to use some meaningful names in the generated software so it can be inspected and understood.

Comment: I've run into this (model state in an abstract way using ngrx in angular). For me, it's best to model ngrx as a participant, so it gets a swim lane. That's arguable, since you do not orchestrate the process of ngrx, you just send stuff in, and get stuff out. It's essentially a black box process, which implies messages. But to equate "ngrx" with "customer" is a pretty broad shot over the bow. Modeled as a process participant, using Data Object References makes it pretty straightforward. A "Collaboration" also works, but that it's a little eclectic.